# How to convert USB to PS/2?

Tags: usb, keyboard

Objective: To get my USB keyboard to interface with an Arduino Uno board.

Constraints: I can't afford a USB host shield for now for Arduino. Currently available is a keyboard with PS/2 connector. That example is available [here](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/PS2Keyboard). However, it is silly going for such a keyboard, or, buy a USB to PS/2 converter at the moment.

Challenge: USB has VCC, GND, RX/TX. (Rx/Tx also labelled D+/D- respectively). The parallel port connector has the following:

[image]

Where will the D- pin go?

Comment: USB doesn't have RX/TX.

Comment: Is there a reason that you think an USB keyboard would work with a PS2 library? These are not the same but two very different means of communication. When wanting to interface an USB slave, you simply have (!) to implement some kind of an USB master. Thats how USB works.

Comment: @chrisl Many USB keyboards can also work as PS/2 keyboards. Plug them into one of those green USB to PS/2 converters and it becomes a PS/2 keyboard. There's no electronics in those converters, it's just a plug. It's down to the keyboard to recognise it's plugged into PS/2 not USB and change its behaviour. Not all keyboards can do it, but certainly most older ones can. I doubt wireless ones would work.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I thought the green/white wires correspond to TX/RX respectively...

Comment: @chrisl heard keyboard MCUs do support both protocols...so I have to discover for myself what is the case with my keyboard... :(

Comment: @deostroll USB uses "low voltage differential signals". It is half duplex (only sends or receives, never both at once) and sends the signal twice - once normally (D+) and once inverted (D-). At the receiver the two signals are combined (D- is inverted, then added to D+) to cancel out any common mode (inducted) noise. This allows higher speeds over longer distances. RS-485 uses the same technique for traditional UART communications over very long distances.

Answer (score 5):

Many USB keyboards (certainly older ones, though almost certainly not wireless ones) are also PS/2 keyboards.  The wiring of the cable is all that differs, and the chip in the keyboard changes its behaviour depending on how it's wired.

A simple USB to PS/2 adaptor is merely a USB socket and PS/2 plug wired together in a certain way:

[image]

So that's:

- 5V to 5V
- D- to Data
- D+ to Clock
- GND to GND

It *may* work with your keyboard, or it may not. All you can do is try it and see.